# Angular: Keep model data in sync with database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm making my first weapons with Angular. I cannot understand the best way to handle data modifications in model and store it in the database, e.g:

In controller:

```
$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, status: 0, data: 'Foo Item' }
    { id: 2, status: 0, data: 'Foooo' }
    { id: 3, status: 1, data: 'OooItem' }
];
```

In view:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'-id'">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.data}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="status(item.id, 1)">Acept</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="status(item.id, 2)">Reject</button>
            </div>                    
        </td>
    </tr>
```

What should I do to update the item status to 1 or 2? Make a call to the server, and then retrieve the new model? Update the model data with JS, and make the call? Is any way to do it automatic? Angular provide some method to access to the current "clicked" item to update the prop (status in this case)?

Hope I was clear.
Thanks.

**EDIT:** So, based on Dr Jones comment, i write this using underscore.

```
function status(id, status) {
    $http.put().then()....
    //after success response, update the model
    item = _.find($scope.items, function (rw) {
        return rw.id == id
    });

    item.status = status;
}
```

This is a valid and correct way to this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it's really up to you.  As with all async programming you have the option to 'auto-sync' or sync as a result of a user event (e.g. hitting a save button).  It really depends on how your app is designed.

Frameworks like firebase (angular-fire lib) have handy built in auto-sync functionality, alternatively the REST Post/Put request is a more traditional design pattern.

Comment: Ok got it! But suppose i will not use any extra framework. So I need to call the API, exec the updated operation, and get a response in the UI. My concern is: I need to find in the model the item by the ID received from the server, and sync this data, right?

Comment: Correct - it really depends on the context of how your app is built and how expensive it is to refresh the data.  So most of the time you may just refresh the data after doing a save.  However if calling the data is slow, you may just update the client side model with the new information.  Typically I choose to refresh from the server if a model has been updated so I can be sure that I have the latest data after an update.